# Unable to call VBA function from Excel Worksheet Cell

Tags: excel, vba

While trying to use a custom made VBA function from an excel worksheet cell, I get the error:
"The formula you typed contains an error"

However, when I call the same function from VBA, it works alright.

VBA Function:

```
Public Function R1C1_value(RowIndex As Integer, ColIndex As Integer, Optional WorkSheetName As String) As Variant
    Dim ws As WorkSheet
    If Trim(WorkSheetName) = "" Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WorkSheetName)
    End If
    R1C1_value = ws.Cells(RowIndex, ColIndex).Value
End Function
```

VBA Function Call:

```
Sub R1C1_value_test()
    Dim res
    res = R1C1_value(1, 9, "CVP")
    MsgBox "res: " & res
End Sub
```

Excel Function call

```
=R1C1_value(1,9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function name is not a Valid name in Excel, even though it is accepted in VBA.  If you change it to xR1C1_value, your function should work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. BTW, what is the reason behind this?

Comment: It is not clear to me, from Excel HELP, why this particular string should be rejected by Excel.  Names cannot conflict with cell addresses, or with Excel built-in names; but it seems there are other, undocumented, reasons for rejection also.

Comment: i'm guessing that because `R1` is a valid address for a cell, it wouldn't be able to tell if you were talking about a cell value or not

Comment: @DLeh Your comment does not make sense to me. The function name was not `R1`  and the string `R1C1_value` is not a valid cell address.  Furthermore, even if you posit that a function name that starts with something that might be a valid cell address will be rejected, a function name like `A1C1_value`, which is of the same format, will be accepted.

Comment: You didn't provide much information about what was invalid, I was just taking a guess. So it's something specific to `R1C1` that is invalid? I'm having trouble getting excel to find functions I call and was trying to figure out if it was because the function name could be trying to parse as a cell address or something

Comment: @DLeh You can find rules for valid names in Excel, by looking at Excel `HELP` and searching for `Valid Names`  Then check the syntax.  Cell addresses are not allowed, nor is `R1C1`, but that was not what was being used in the above.  If you cannot figure out your problem, post a question with the specifics.